# Diagnosing IronPython StackOverflowException

Tags: python, stack-overflow, iron

I have a program that essentially reads a temp sensor and writes the readings to a file in an infinite loop (i.e. keep running until I crash/exit the program). Worked great on first machine - Iron Python 2.7, MS Visual Studio 2015 and Win 7 Professional. Trying on second machine - Iron Python 2.7.6, latest version of Visual Studio 2015 and I get "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException". Note the program will operate, but reliably halts with Stack Overflow in about 2-3minutes of operation. I have no clue on how to debug. Is this a setup issue?

Self Diagnosis:
Looks like this is a question of default environment - problem exhibited when I run is Iron Python 64 bit. Changed default environment to other version and this issue went away

Comment: There is no enough information in your post for us to be able to say anything about it. It looks like your program is using too much memory by calling a lot of functions inefficiently. Please at least post the code inside your infinite loop.

Comment: It seems you suspect this to be a bug in IronPython - in that case you should file a bug report on [their Github page](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/issues). Otherwise you have not provided enough information for us to help (or asked an actual question)